# It does not print the name after the input

Tags: dart

I was doing a input and yeah i can put my name, but it didn't do the print and I don't know why

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("Enter name:");
  String? name  = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("The entered name is ${name}");
}
```

I tried a lot of things and i don't what to do.

Comment: How were you running this?  "dart filename.dart"?

Comment: which ide are you using to run it? it is working on jdoodle if you want to try : https://jdoodle.com/ia/zZv

Comment: Yeah i was running in the debugger but now I configure it to run in the terminal and it works, thank you very much